# Access UI Elements in ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using a Windows Ribbon. In the ribbon there is a button called 'Cancel'.

My code is set up in the following way:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:TestViewModel}">
            <testViews:TestView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources> 
    <Ribbon>
        <RibbonButton x:Name="CancelButton" Click="CancelButton_OnClick">
    </Ribbon>   
    <ContentControl Name="MasterContentControl" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />     
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs code-behind:

```
private void CancelButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /*
      Here I need to somehow execute this code:
      DataGridInTestView.ExecuteCommand(DataPresenterCommands.EndEditModeAndDiscardChanges);
    */
}
```

TestView.xaml:

```
<UserControl>
<XamDataGrid Name="DataGridInTestView">
</UserControl>
```

What I need to happen is to get a handle on the DataGridInTestView control in TestView so I can execute some code when someone 
presses the Cancel in the Windows Ribbon.How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please use 'x:Name' instead of 'Name' in your XamDataGrid and try to reference 'DataGridInTestView' from code behind.

Comment: what is TestView ? another window ?

Comment: TestView is the name of the user control. <UserControl></UserControl> .